# Shared VirtualHost File - Multiple Servers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, lamp

We currently operate multiple LAMP servers (clustered) and have several VirtualHost config files.

We don't want to have to SCP the file between servers (SPOF). Is that the best bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better/more semantic way to handle this?

Use mod_vhost_alias without changing config later at all?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use a configuration management tool like Puppet or Chef to manage the configurations on the different servers.